# JQuery fade effect for background image on mouseenter

Tags: jquery, background-image, fade, effect, mouseenter

I want to add a JQuery fade effect for my navigation on mouseenter of a button. I have created a mouseover style in my CSS already, but without fade for browsers who do not have javascript activated.

My structure: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoze559h/3/)

```
#menu li:hover {
 background-image: url(http://file2.npage.de/012690/81/bilder/menu_sub_hover.png);
 }
```

In this code is the pic, which opens on mouseover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

If you wish to use Jquery then you should use .fadeTo(duration, opacity)

Here is a quick code example

```
$('.fade')
  .on('mouseenter', function(){$(this).fadeTo(400,.5);})
  .on('mouseleave', function(){$(this).fadeTo(400,1);});
```

Fiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/eoze559h/7/

---

If you wish to do a fade why not do it all with CSS as well?

Fiddel:http://jsfiddle.net/eoze559h/5/

Here is the CSS code example:

```
.fade {

    opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}
.fade:hover {
      opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that css3 transition property does not work for background-images that he wants to be added on `:hover`..

Comment: oh sry my english is so bad.. =) i want a jquery effect not css.

Comment: For old browser won´t work your method, and for them i will use the hover without fade and add the fade with jquery for new browser.

Comment: Thank you for your code example but how can i use this on my code and on my background-image?

Comment: If i try with transition, the text in the button must have a opacity. It will only work with another structure...

Comment: Yeah, if you only want the background-image to fade while not affecting the other elements there is really only two ways I can think to do this. One, make separate elements that are with-in your list items and toggle them with JQuery like I showed. Or Two, you can use CSS to append a pseudo element and toggle that element's opacity. Here is an example of the latter. http://jsfiddle.net/eoze559h/9/

Answer (score 0):

i try, but i am not sure with this solution, maybe use just css

Need jquery library !

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/axelschouten/eoze559h/4/)

```
$("#navi li a").hover(function(){
$(this).addClass("hover");
},function(){
$(this).removeClass("hover");
});
```

Comment: Why would he want to add a class that contains css property `background: red;`? The problem is that css3 transition does not fully support background-image property.

Comment: My image should fade not a background color =).